# a matrix of rank $r$ satisfies a polynomial of degree $r+1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers, contest-math, minimal-polynomials

Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb C$. Suppose $M$ has rank $r$ with $r<n$. Prove there is a polynomial $P(x)$ with degree $r+1$ and coefficients in $\mathbb C$ such that $P(M)$ is the zero matrix.

I think this has to do with the minimal/characteristic polynomials, although I have not yet seen this in school. I would appreciate a comprehensive solution, hopefully referencing the theorems as they are used.

Comment: Do you know Jordan canonical form?

Comment: no, I do not know Jordan canonical  I'm supposed to see that this semester.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Small variation of the answer of loup blanc that does not mention minimal polynomials, and produces an actual annihilating polynmial of degree $r+1$. Note that is is irrelevant that the vector space is over$~\Bbb C$.

The image space $W$ of $M$ (or column space if you prefer) has dimension $r$ by definition of the rank. The characteristic polynomial $Q$ of the endomorphism of$~W$ obtained by restriction of $M$ has degree$~r$ (one can compute this polynomial by expressing the restriction as an $r\times r$ matrix on some basis of the image). Then by Cayley-Hamilton, the restriction of $Q[M]$ to $W$ is zero, i.e., $Q[M]$ vanishes on$~W$. Since $W$ is the image of$~M$, this implies that $(QX)[M]=Q[M]\cdot M=0$, and $QX$ is our annihilating polynmial of degree $r+1$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\dim(\ker(M))=n-r$, there is an invertible matrix $P$ s.t. $P^{-1}MP=\begin{pmatrix}0_{n-r}&A\\0&B_r\end{pmatrix}$. Let $P$ be the minimal polynomial of $B_r$; its degree is $\leq r$. Finally, the minimal polynomial of $M$ divides $xP(x)$ and we are done.

Comment: Why the minimal polynomial of M divides xp(x) ? I can't understand why $P^{-1}MP$ is a root of xp(x) ?

Comment: @ user371231 , you downvote my post, that you did not understand, before having the answer to your question. Incredible...

Comment: Sorry for that..now I understand my misunderstanding.I will upvote it immediately it works.